# Web server URL rewriting

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, nginx

I would like to make a URL rewriting configuration to d othe following:

1. Allowing my website URL to appear like site.com/category/item (redirected to index.php?c=$1&i=$2)
2. Allowing files to be included from directories like config (site.com/config/conf.txt)
3. Redirect the URL like site.com/admin/category/item to admin.php?c=$1&i=$2

So far, i managed to set up these 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^\.^/]+)$ index.php?c=$1&i=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^/]+)$ $1
```

These work for the first 2 items, but I can't manage to find the third one that would work with the existing rules...

For the moment I am using Apache, but I am also looking forward using NGinx. That would be great if the rules were compatible.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: You're still unknown unless your First name is `user` and your Last name  `573152` (in which case I will apologize of course).

Comment: Why should anonymity be always a bad idea? I am reluctant to those 'social' networks for a reason. This site gave me a numbered username, I am comfortable with it. Can we get back to the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !config
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^\.^/]+)$ index.php?c=$1&i=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !config
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z]+)/([^\.^/]+)$ admin.php?c=$1&i=$2 [L]
```

Translation: if the URI doesn't begin with `/config/` then (only then) try to apply the other rewriterule, thus "allowing files to be included from directories like config (site.com/config/conf.txt)" **and** still applying the rules to other URLs.

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: First, thanks for the help. I tried that, but the config thing didn't work. When trying to include the config file from a PHP file, then when I try to access `site.com/category/item`, I get the following error: `The requested URL /category/config/config.txt was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this hint: the log explains it all about the process followed by the rewriting! Nice to see that the conditions are checked after a rule matches... even if the multi-threaded accesses to the log file makes it lokking like a spaghetti bowl.

Here are the rules I used:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/config/([^\.]+/)*[a-z\.^/]+$
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([^\.^/]+)$ index.php?c=$1&i=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/config/([^\.]+/)*[a-z\.^/]+$
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z]+)/([^\.^/]+)$ admin.php?c=$1&i=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /config/([^\.]+/)*[a-z\.^/]+$
RewriteRule /config/(([^\.]+/)*[a-z\.^/]+)$ config/$1 [L]
```

I started by checking the URL from the end and not from the start, since those rules can then be applied in a subdirectory of the root.
I allowed subdirectories in the config directory to be called.
The last rule is reentrant, but avoid another rewrting if the rules are applied in the root directory. If not, the expression doesn't match and the rule is applied to produce an output identical to the input.

In general, there is no mean to avoid the server to apply once again the redirection rules to a previously redirected URI. The documentation tells about an [END] flag to do so, but I haven't been able to put that into practice successfully...
Thus, to me, all the htaccess rules shall be reentrant.